# sas macro to read multiple multsheet excel in folder

Tags: sas

this is my code to read multiple multisheet excel in sas its giving an error which i am attaching in last.i am only reading first sheet named summary of every excel in that particular folder

```
%macro sks2sas01(input=d:\excels,out=work.tt);    
/* read files in directory */
%let dir=%str(%'dir %")&input.%str(\%" /A-D/B/ON%');
filename myfiles pipe %unquote(&dir);
data list1; length fname $256.;
infile myfiles truncover;
input myfiles $100.;
/* put _infile_;*/
fname=quote(upcase(cats("&input",'\',myfiles)));
out="&out";
drop myfiles;
call execute('
PROC IMPORT DBMS=EXCEL2002 OUT= _1
DATAFILE= '||fname||' REPLACE ;
sheet="summary";
RUN;
proc append data=_1 base='||out||' force; run;
proc delete data=_1; run;
');
run;
filename myfiles clear;

%mend sks2sas01;

%sks2sas01(input=c:\sasupload\excels,out=work.tt);
```

hereby i am attaching error i am getting:

```
GOPTIONS ACCESSIBLE;
%macro sks2sas01(input=d:\excels,out=work.tt);
     /* read files in directory */
     %let dir=%str(%'dir %")&input.%str(\%" /A-D/B/ON%');
     filename myfiles pipe %unquote(&dir);
     data list1; length fname $256.;
     infile myfiles truncover;
     input myfiles $100.;
     /* put _infile_;*/
     fname=quote(upcase(cats("&input",'\',myfiles)));
     out="&out";
     drop myfiles;
     call execute('
     PROC IMPORT DBMS=EXCEL2002 OUT= _1
     DATAFILE= '||fname||' REPLACE ;
     sheet="summary";
     RUN;
     proc append data=_1 base='||out||' force; run;
     proc delete data=_1; run;
     ');
     run;
     filename myfiles clear;

     %mend sks2sas01;

     %sks2sas01(input=c:\sasupload\excels,out=work.tt);
ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access PIPE.
ERROR: Error in the FILENAME statement.
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the necessary authorisation for the `filename myfiles pipe <directory>` command line

Comment: dear bendy , but i have already provided all the authorizations....

Comment: Which version of SAS are you using? You can't use pipe filenames or execute any sort of shell commands in SAS University Edition, for example.

Comment: hm, %unquote(&dir) resolves to 'dir "c:\sasupload\excels\" /A-D/B/ON', not sure about the additional " inside when using pipe, shouldnt it be 'dir c:\sasupload\excels\ /A-D/B/ON' ? At least in examples i saw, there are always only outer Quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem the other day. I had no authorization for the `pipe` command, and `dir` using sftp wasn't working for me either.  This alternative solution worked great for me. In a nutshell, you're going to use some oldschool SAS directory commands to read every file within that directory, and save only the ones that end in `.xlsx`.

You can consider the name of your Excel files `.`-delimited, scan the filename of each one backwards, and look at just the first word to obtain only those Excel files. For example:

`File name.xlsx`

Backwards:

```
 Delimiter
    v 
xlsx.name File
^^^^
First word
```

**Step 1: Read all XLSX files in the directory, and create a dataset of them**

```
filename dir 'C:\MyDirectory';

data XLSX_Files;
    DirID = dopen("dir");

    do i = 1 to dnum(DirID);
        file_name = dread(DirID, i);
        if(upcase(scan(file_name, 1, '.', 'b') ) = 'XLSX') then output;
    end;

    rc=dclose(DirID);

    drop i rc DirID;    
run;
```

**Step 2: Read all of those names into a pipe-delimited macro variable**

```
proc sql noprint;
    select file_name, count(file_name)
    into :XLSX_Files separated by '|',
         :tot_files
    from XLSX_Files;
quit;
```

**Step 3: Import them all in a macro loop**

```
%macro import_all;
    %do i = 1 %to &tot_files;
        proc import file="C:\MyDirectory\%scan(&XLSX_Files,&i,|)"
            out=XLSX_&i
            dbms=xlsx replace;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;
%import_all;
```

You can then stack or merge them as you need.

```
data Master_File;
    set XLSX_1-XLSX_&tot_files;
run;
```

OR

```
data Master_File;
    merge XLSX_1-XLSX_&tot_files;
    by key;
run;
```